# Remove the tablesorterpager and then put it back again

Tags: jquery, html, tablesorter, jquery-pagination

I have the table generated dynamically, at times it will have 100 rows other times it may have 300. I wish to put tablesorterpager on my table.

When the user hits find to repopulate the table, I wish to unbind or remove the pagers action, load the data and then bind the plugin again. Any ideas on how i can achieve the bind -unbind operation on th tablesorterpager action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I put these in the pager plugin before the constructors solved my issue**

```
                 $(config.cssNext,pager).unbind('click');
                 $(config.cssPrev,pager).unbind('click');
                 $(config.cssFirst,pager).unbind('click');
                 $(config.cssLast,pager).unbind('click');
```

**constructor within "....pager.js":**

```
                $(config.cssFirst,pager).click(function() {
                    moveToFirstPage(table);
                    return false;
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a fork of [tablesorter](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter) on Github. And the pager plugin has a method to enable, disable or completely destroy the pager plugin. [Here is a demo](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-pager.html).

Also, if it helps, there is another demo on how to use the pager plugin to use [ajax data](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-pager-ajax.html).

Comment: @fudgey- the line `$('table').trigger('destroy.pager');` does it clear the pager variables, can you elaborate on your fork.

Comment: No, it just removes the pager from the table. The pager variables are not modified, but if the pager is reinitialized, the default settings will be applied unless options are added.